# problems python socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I have problems i'cant run this script
I tried creating an ICMP network sniffer as follows:

```
import socket
import os

host = '192.168.1.9'

if os.name == "nt":
   socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
else:
   socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP
   sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW,socket_protocol)
   sniffer.bind((host, 0))   

   sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

if os.name == "nt":

  sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
  print sniffer.recvfrom(656565)

if os.name == "nt":

  sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "exampl.py", line 11, in <module>
sniffer.bind((host, 6000))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

What can I do to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
> ```
>
> What can I do to prevent this error?

The name of errno 99 is defined by

```
#define EADDRNOTAVAIL   99      /* Cannot assign requested address */
```

and `man bind` says:

```
   EADDRNOTAVAIL
          A  nonexistent  interface was requested or the requested address
          was not local.
```

This suggests trying with a local address, and indeed there's no more error with:

```
host = 'localhost'
```

Comment: Why would he have to change the address to local host that is not the objective

Comment: You haven't recognized that _the objective_ is _to prevent this error_.